# How to distribute unique generated rocks on a surface

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I'm generating unique rocks through the lower left group of nodes, and I'm trying to distribute them throughout a surface. The problem is that it's only taking a single unique rock instead of using a different one for each instance.

I tried using the "pick instance" checkboxes but these just make them all disappear.

[image: Geometry node setup]

Comment: May I recommend to read these two posts: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/280188/why-cant-the-radius-of-an-icosphere-be-set-depending-on-position-with-geometry and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274485/how-can-i-instantiate-a-procedural-node-group-with-different-parameters ?

Comment: That was it, thank you!